# Owl carousel 2 - sometimes photos won't load

Tags: slider, owl-carousel

I've searched internet wide, but I can't find any issue like this...
When I refresh webpage with my owl my photos wont load and i get only something like this:
[image]

It doesn't happen on every refresh but let's say every 4-5...
It'll display photos when I scroll to another one...

here is my js:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
var $owl = $('.owl-carousel');
$owl.owlCarousel({
    loop:true,
    center: true,
    dots:false,
    margin: 15,
    responsiveClass:true,
    autoWidth: true,
    autoHeight: true,
    autoplay: true,
    autoplayTimeout: 5000,
    autoplayHoverPause: true,
    responsive:{
        0:{
            items: 1,
            nav: false
        },
        600:{
            items: 1,
            nav: false
        },
        1000:{
            items: 1,
            nav: false
        }
    }
});
$owl.on('mousewheel', '.owl-stage', function (e) {
    if (e.deltaY>0) {
        $owl.trigger('next.owl');
    } else {
        $owl.trigger('prev.owl');
    }
    e.preventDefault();
 });
});
```

my html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <title>Light Coorporation - Photo</title>
    <?php include '../include/header_template.php' ?>
    <link href="../owlcarousel/assets/owl.carousel.css"     rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="../owlcarousel/assets/owl.theme.default.min.css"     rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="../owlcarousel/assets/owl.theme.dots.modified.css"     rel="stylesheet">
</head>
<body>
    <?php include '../include/fixed_menu.php' ?>
    <br><br><br><br>
    <div class="wrapper col-xs-12 wrapper-photo" style="display:     none;">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="owl-carousel">
                <div class="item custom-photo-width"><img     src="../images/photo/01-04.jpg"></div>
                <div class="item custom-photo-width"><img     src="../images/photo/01-06.jpg"></div>
                <div class="item custom-photo-width"><img     src="../images/photo/01-07.jpg"></div>
                <div class="item custom-photo-width"><img     src="../images/photo/01-08.jpg"></div>
                <div class="item custom-photo-width"><img     src="../images/photo/02-04.jpg"></div>
               ...more photos...
            </div>
        </div>
        <br><br>
        </div>
        <script src="../owlcarousel/owl.carousel.min.js"></script>
        <script src="../js/owl_custom.min.js"></script>
        <script src="../js/jquery.mousewheel.min.js"></script>
    <script>
        $('.wrapper').fadeIn(1500);
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

result:
http://bez-granic.eu/lc/photo

Comment: You don't need to set `responsive` option if you always have same responsive settings.

Answer (score 2):

You have a race condition between loading images and activating carousel on DOM ready event. 
Just move your owl call to window.load event and it will solve the issue. Load event fires up when all the images are finished loading.

Comment: `autoWidth: true, autoHeight: true,` this 2 defs had a influence on the carousel , removing it helped but then broke the width so implementing this on window load worked really good, thanks for idea.